# Is there a site like soundcomparisons.com for French?

Tags: ressources, accents-régionaux

[Soundcomparisons.com](http://soundcomparisons.com/) is a great site for listening to how a certain word is pronounced in different accents of English from all over the English-speaking world. Is there a site like this for French? That has the possibility to listen to **the same word or the same sentences** in different accents of French. It does not have to cover all French speaking countries. I'd be happy with just France.

Comment: to my knowledge there aren't so much well-established, evolved and specific dialects in French when compared for instance to Germany, where pure dialect speakers north vs. south and east vs. west have a hard time understanding each other, so TV stations often show standard German subtitles in bavarian TV ;)

Comment: It seems like you're right, @Hauser. [BBC reported 2011](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/europe/1373908.stm) that "Compared with Britain, France has extremely few regional accents", although what accents there are, they seem to have become more appreciated lately.

Answer (score 3):

You may try [accents de france](http://accentsdefrance.free.fr/) for accents from France.

There are much more differences with Quebec, Switzerland, Belgium, North African and Central African countries.